# Script that captures facebook email

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some script that can extract email and facebook.
 I do not know if this can be done. I am open to suggestions. Like the technology to use.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Webscraping with node Js.
[x-ray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-ray) is the easiest tool for web-scraping
you can extract email & FB link by giving its DOM location ...